# Can't load information from cassandra database from pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have this code:

```py
import os
from pyspark import SparkContext,SparkFiles,SQLContext,SparkFiles
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

secure_bundle_file=os.getcwd()+'\\secure-connect-dbtest.zip'
sparkSession =SparkSession.builder.appName('SparkCassandraApp')\
  .config('spark.cassandra.connection.config.cloud.path',secure_bundle_file)\
  .config('spark.cassandra.auth.username', 'test')\
  .config('spark.cassandra.auth.password','testquart')\
  .config('spark.dse.continuousPagingEnabled',False)\
  .master('local[*]').getOrCreate()

data = sparkSession.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
  .options(table="tbthesis", keyspace="test").load()
data.count()
```

What I try to do is to connect to my database and retrieve my data. The code connects well to the database but once it arrives to read line it says:

```
Exception has occurred: Py4JJavaError
An error occurred while calling o48.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra. 
Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:674)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSourceV2(DataSource.scala:728)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:230)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:203)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
```

Can someone help me, please?

Also, I want to add some more details about this code:

What I want to do is to test how much time does spark last to read 2 million records from my database, normal python-cassandra driver read 2 million records in about 1 hour (using SimpleStatement) so here I want to know how much it would last using spark with those 2 M records.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't have Spark Cassandra Connector package in your classpath, so it can't find corresponding classes.

You need to start your job (`spark-submit` or `pyspark`) with `--packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.5.1`.

If you really want to do it from the python code only, then you may try to add `.config("spark.jars.packages", "com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.5.1")` when creating `SparkSession`, but it may not always work, if classpath is already instantiated.

P.S. Spark usually should outperform `SimpleStatement`, even in the local mode, although Spark is really shines in the distributed mode.  You really shouldn't use `SimpleStatement` for repeatedly execute the query that is different only in parameters - you should use [prepared statements](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.24/getting_started/#prepared-statement) for that. Please read [Developing applications with DataStax drivers](https://docs.datastax.com/en/devapp/doc/devapp/aboutDrivers.html) guide.  DataStax also gives away a 3rd edition of the [Cassandra. The Definitive Guide](https://www.datastax.com/resources/ebook/oreilly-cassandra-definitive-guide) book - just fresh off the press - I recommend to read it.

Comment: I'm confused, I just downloaded those to some jar folder, which is not the spark/folder but it's the location where the dowload process did. Now, is there a way to include "--packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.5.1" within python code and not through console? like using os.environ?

Comment: Or even better, what is the correct way to add packages in the python code?

Comment: I did apply pyspark --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.5.1 and I got this error " Java gateway process exited before sending its port number" I think this com.datastax.spark connector is the missing link to get my data, all what you have told me today has worked, this is the only part missing. Thanks for your help

Comment: Use .config piece that I described

Comment: Okay, I applied that ".config(...)" I added the packages but I had the same error. When you say "classpath" you are refering to an environment  variable? And if it is so, then I want to understand something...I have some packages in my spark/jar folder and some other in some temporary folder, does the "classpath" have the rest of pakages that are not originally in spark/jar ?

Comment: Try to remove downloaded jar from spark directory. The code that was shown is previous answer was completely tested. And you don’t really need to do everything from Python, it’s even discouraged - you’ll need to change source code if you change password, or file, etc. Spark allows to specify configuration from the outside. I recommend to read “Learning Spark” book - it’s freely available from the Databricks site, look into resources section

Comment: Okay, well, if you insist about this then it must be something that matters. So , my question is, if I run once the spark configuration in console, you mean that this configuration will remain until I run it again with different values? And so if I use my python code it will be to get the data from the configuration already set in spark console? Or will I have to set the configuration in spark console everytime? Thanks for the book, I will definately read it.

Comment: No. Configuration values need to be passed on every run. To simplify, you can put them into a properties file and pass the name of the file in command line. My point is that it’s usually better not to hard code configuration in the code

Comment: I don't have downloaded jars in my original spark/jars folder, all the downloaded jars are in a different folder which the process selected.

Comment: Got you, no configuration code in code, that's true.

Comment: Well, this is getting interesting...So, now my question would be: The main goal is to create an app,probably a web site in django that uses machine learning with python and retrieve data through spark cassandra, then to make the web site runs , and following your idea, the best way would be to run the spark console with that properties file and the rest of processes directly in python, right?

Comment: I don’t think that it’s how Spark and Cassandra works. You need to find an another approach to this task - except when your doing the inference, but even in that case you don’t need spark

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved.

The problem was not java,hadoop or spark, was the download process of the connector, but I could not download anything because my cache folder for this jars had things on it.

The folder where my spark downloads external jars is C:\Users\UlysesRico.ivy2\jars The cache for it is C:\Users\UlysesRico.ivy2\cache

I just erased cache and jars foldes, then I did:

pyspark --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.5.1
And voilá, I downloaded all the jars and cache information for it.

Problem finally solved.